# Jersey Client returns HTTP 204 in a post method while trying to send jsonObject

Tags: java, json, rest, post, jersey

Hey so I'm trying to send some json-object to a rest web service, then get the value of some specific keys, then process the data to finally return a new json-object  which is going to be used in another place. Anyway, I'm getting HTTP 204 when I try to communicate with the service.

My rest service looks like this

```
@Path("/example")
public class PdfMaker { 

@POST
@Path("/post")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response PruebasMet(JSONObject json) throws IOException, JSONException{
        try{
            String xml = json.getString("xml");
            String plantilla = json.getString("plant");

        //method that uses "xml" and "plant" and returns "pdf" 

        JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
        response.put("pdf", pdf);

    return Response.status(200).entity(pdfb64.toString()).build();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.getStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

}
```

and I'm trying to communicate with this

```
public class Jersey {

public static String baseuri = "http://localhost:8080/PdfMakerGF/rest/example/post";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
        Client client = Client.create(config);
        WebResource webResource = client.resource(baseuri);
        JSONObject objTest = new JSONobject();
        objTest.put("xml","Data1");
        objTest.put("plan", "Data2");


        ClientResponse res = webResource.header("Content-Type","application/json;charset=UTF-8")
       .post(ClientResponse.class, objTest.toString());

        System.out.println("output..." + "\n");

        System.out.println("Answer "+res);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But the response that I receive is this one

> Answer POST http://localhost:8080/PdfMakerGF/rest/example/post
>   returned a response status of 204 No Content

Obviously there is something wrong but can't see what is it.
Since I'm stuck with this. Any kind of help would be appreciated. 
I'm using netbeans 8.1, Glassfish 4.1 and Jersey.
Thanks

Comment: Also the Service has been proved with a xml form and works fine

Comment: Have you checked your server logs for exceptions?

Comment: Have you tried sending the same request via Postman?

Comment: Postman retrieves the same code (204) and by some reason glassfish is not posting any info , as long as i understand is problem of the rest service, mostly in the "return segment" a coworker says something about an Entity as return instead of a jsonobject (changing the service as public Response..)

Comment: ago21 20175:08:14 PMcom.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFORMACIÓN:1*Clientout-boundrequest
1>POST http://localhost:8080/PdfMakerGF/rest/example/post
1>Content-type:application/json;Charset=UTF-8
1>Accept:application/json
{"xml":"data"}
ago 21, 2017 5:08:14PMcom.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFORMACIÓN:1*Clientin-bound response
1<204
1<Server:GlassFishServer OpenSource Edition4.1
1<Date:Mon,21Aug201722:08:14GMT
1<X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1 JSP/2.3 (GlassFishServer OpenSource Edition4.1Java/Oracle Corporation/1.8)<--thats the only info that im getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okey so finaly it works what i need to change was the way that the service was reciving the data, with a inner class in my case,  end up working like this ..

```
Class Aux{
String xml;
String plant;
//generate gettes and setters :)
}
@Path("/example")
public class PdfMaker { 
@POST
@Path("/post")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response PruebasMet(Aux json) throws IOException, 
JSONException{
    try{
    String xml = json.getXml();
    String plant = json.getPlant();
    //method that uses "xml" and "plant" and returns "pdf" 

    JSONObject response = new JSONObject();
    response.put("pdf", pdf);

return Response.status(200).entity(pdf)).build();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.getStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

}

and the client is ..

```
Client client = new Client();
    WebResource wresource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/PdfMakerGF/rest/example/post");
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("xml", DATA);
    json.put("plant", DATA);

        ClientResponse response =  
        wresource.type("application/json").post(ClientResponse.class, 
        json.toString());

        out = response.getEntity(String.class);
        System.out.println("RES = "+response);
        System.out.println("OUT = "+out);
```

out has the info that the service is Providing

Comment: I hope this can help someone

Answer (score 0):

If your server runs into an exception and goes to the catch block, it returns null which corresponds to HTTP 204 (No Content). As sisyphus commented, there should be some exception in the server standard output.

So you probably need to:

- Return a different response code (e.g. INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR or
  BAD_REQUEST) in the catch block
- Check why the server code is throwing
  the exception

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you get an Exception. I guess it is because you have "plant" in one place and "plan" in another.

Comment: that's acctualy a misatake that I made when I paste the data, anyways thaks for your hlep